# how to insert text inside the trapezium in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

could you please tell me how to insert text inside the trapezium in css ? 
Actually I do like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
         <div id="triangle-topleft">
404
         </div>

     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
 #container {
     width:200px;
    }
   #triangle-topleft {
       width: 200px;
       height: 0;
       border-top: 100px solid #ccc;
       border-right: 200px solid transparent;
   }
```

I want `404` text should display inside the trapezium..

[image]

here is my code

https://jsbin.com/gucuviqigi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Here my answer.

You can play with Top = % and left % to move it as you want :)

Don't forget to mark it as accepted:

```css
 #container {
     width:200px;
    }
   #triangle-topleft {
       width: 200px;
       height: 0;
       border-top: 100px solid #ccc;
       border-right: 200px solid transparent;
   }
   
  .number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
         <div id="triangle-topleft">
<div class="number">
404
</div>
</div>
         </div>

     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if I add header in my html ..I need to change `top` value ..I want responsive solution ..as I try to give `relative` position to my paent `div` and `absolute` to child but it also not work

Comment: I'll try adding it with before in css. Wait a sec